# Display data in single column

Tags: reporting-services, visual-studio-2015

I have a table as shown below:

Table 1

[image]

I need to display data like below. I have tried using grouping but but i failed.
I have read some topics but can't find the solution. This should not be that hard.

Table 2

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get that using `LookupSet` over a dumb group.

Add a tablix to your report and add a parent group in the `Row Groups` pane.

[image]

Use the below expression to create the group.

```
=1
```

That expression will create only one group, and you will have something like this in design.

[image]

Then use this expression in the highlighted cell in my screenshot above.

```
=join(
LookupSet(1,1,Fields!ColumnA.Value,"DataSetName")," - ")
```

Where `Fields!ColumnA.Value` is the field of `X`, `Y` and `Z` values, and DataSetName should be the name of your dataset.

You will get this result.

[image]

If you have repeated values in `ColumnA` they will appear repeated too in the cell. You will have to filter your dataset to get only unique values.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! It worked ! You are the king of the north !

Comment: i have a new requirement. What should i do if the 2 rows of column has the same value ? Because its showing like X - Y - Y.